# Using Newton's Method to simplify Trapezoidal Method

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I have the following initial value problem on $t \in [0,T]$: $$y'=y^2(1-\epsilon y)$$

I wish to use the Trapezoidal method to solve this I.V.P., and I cannot use simply use the predictor-corrector method, i.e. improved Euler's method. The trapezoidal method is defined by: $$y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{h}{2}(f_{n+1}+f_n)$$ Plugging in the value from the O.D.E., we have after some simplification: $$y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{h}{2}(y_{n+1}^2+y_n^2-\epsilon y_{n+1}^3-\epsilon y_n^3)$$

This is an implicit method, so I must use a root finding method at each iteration to find the $y_{n+1}$ on the right side of the equation. I have read online that Newton's method is usually used for such purposes, but I cannot figure out how to implement it.

$$y_{n+1}=y_n-\frac{f(y_n)}{f'(y_n)}$$

For example, what values would $f(y_n)$ and $f'(y_n)$ take in this context? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole equation is $f$. More precisely, $y_{n+1}$ is the solution of
$$
0=f(y)=y-y_n-\frac h2(y^2+y_n^2-ϵ(y^3+y_n^3))
$$
closest to $y_n$.

---

The derivative is then
$$
f'(y)=1-\frac h2(2y-3ϵy^2)
$$
so that the Newton iteration is
$$
y_+=y-\frac{f(y)}{f'(y)}=\frac{y_n-\frac h2(y^2-y_n^2−ϵ(2y^3-y_n^3))}{1-\frac h2(2y-3ϵy^2)}
$$

Comment: I don't quite understand. So, for each iteration, $y_{n+1}=y-y_n-\frac{h}{2}(y^2+y_n^2-\epsilon(y^3+y_n^3))$ ? Also, what would $f'(y_n)$ be?

Comment: No, why? That would imply $y_{n+1}=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still unsure of how to apply Newton's method to this concept. I know I'm supposed to use it to find an expression for $y_{n+1}$ on the right side.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot! I'm just confused about how the $\epsilon(2y^2-y_n^2)$ term on the numerator. How did those powers of $3$ cancel out?

Comment: Sorry, they don't.